# Group a sequence into buckets based on comparison of discrete keys with interval boundaries

Tags: f#, grouping

The other day, this homework type question ([Create a list of custom type in F# and create two sequences of that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368307/create-a-list-of-custom-type-in-f-and-create-two-sequences-of-that-list)) might have been easily answered, since there are only two possible outcomes (think `List.partition`). It got me wondering how to generalize the grouping into buckets either including or excluding the respective boundary values.

Given an input of `[5; 10; 15; 45; 50; 55]` and interval boundaries of `[10; 20; 50]`, produce two groupings

> ```
> [[5; 10]; [15]; [45; 50]; [55]] // less-than-and-equal
> [[5]; [10; 15]; [45]; [50; 55]] // greater-than-and-equal
> ```

I am probably overthinking this.

```
type 'a ComparisonResult = Under of 'a | Over of 'a

let internal splitter op standardResult extraResultValue boundaries keySelector arg =
    boundaries |> List.tryFind (op (keySelector arg)) |> function
    | None -> extraResultValue
    | Some x -> standardResult x

let under boundaries =  // under and including
    boundaries |> List.rev |> splitter (>) Over (boundaries |> List.head |> Under)

let over boundaries =   // over and including
    boundaries |> splitter (<) Under (boundaries |> List.rev |> List.head |> Over)

[5; 10; 15; 45; 50; 55]
|> Seq.groupBy (under [10; 20; 50] id)
|> printfn "%A"

[5; 10; 15; 45; 50; 55]
|> Seq.groupBy (over [10; 20; 50] id)
|> printfn "%A"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. I guess it does not perform well for a lot of boundaries.

```ml
let chunkByInterval predicate boundaries list =
    list
    |> List.groupBy (fun x -> boundaries |> List.countBy (fun b -> predicate x b))
    |> List.map snd

chunkByInterval (<=) [10; 20; 50] [5; 10; 15; 45; 50; 55] 
// [[5; 10]; [15]; [45; 50]; [55]]

chunkByInterval (>=) [10; 20; 50] [5; 10; 15; 45; 50; 55] 
// [[5]; [10; 15]; [45]; [50; 55]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tail-recursive solution, by going through both the lists together, and accumulating a 'chunk'.

```
let chunkByInterval list intervals compare = 
    let rec chunk list intervals acc = 
        match (acc, list, intervals) with
        | (head::tail), (x::xs as xs'), (y::ys as ys') ->  
            if compare x y then 
                chunk xs ys' ((x::head)::tail) 
            else 
                chunk xs' ys ([]::acc)
        | (_, xs, _) -> xs::acc

    chunk list intervals [[]] |> List.filter (not << List.isEmpty) |> List.map List.rev |> List.rev
```

And usage:

```
chunkByInterval [5; 10; 15; 45; 50; 55] [10; 20; 50] (<=) //[[5; 10]; [15]; [45; 50]; [55]]
```

The slight downside is that since we're accumulating by cons, we have to reverse the list at the end. This also assumes both lists are sorted, but it's often faster to sort them first rather than have an O(n ^ 2) search or use a lookup.

There's an elegant solution to be built with sequence expressions for this very same problem - definitely easier with Interactive Extensions package.